# Cómo puedo hacer la siguiente llamada?

Tags: c++

tengo la siguiente clase:

```
template<class T>
class THashCerrada
{
    public:
        THashCerrada(int nDatos) : datos(nDatos), nDatos(nDatos) {};
        THashCerrada(const THashCerrada& orig);
        bool insertar(long clave, const T& dato);
        bool borrar(long clave, T& resultado);
        bool buscar(long clave, T& resultado);
        unsigned int tamaTabla();
        float factorCarga();
        static int djb2(string codigo);
        unsigned ExploracionCuadratica(unsigned long n, int i);

    private:
        vector<Casilla<T>> datos;
        //vector<T> datos;
        int nDatos;
};
```

Y la implementación de la función `insertar()` es:

```
bool THashCerrada<T>::insertar(long clave, const T& dato)
{
    int in = 0;
    auto pos = ExploracionCuadratica(clave, in);

    if (datos.at(pos).disponible == '0' || datos.at(pos).disponible == '1')
    {
        datos.at(pos).dato = dato;
        datos.at(pos).disponible = '2';
        nDatos++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Yo he creado la tabla `THashCerrada<string> table(13434)`
y quiero llamar a `insertar` para introducir un dato en la tabla pero no sé qué tengo que poner en el segundo parámetro de `table.insertar(p1,p2)`.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que quieres **incrementar** `nDatos` cada vez que llamas a `insertar`? Lo digo porque lo inicializas con un valor en el constructor (`13434` en tu ejemplo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `THashCerrada` es un template, tal y como se indica en su declaración:

```
template<class T>
class THashCerrada
```

Ello implica que el tipo para el cual se especializa hay que indicarlo al crear la clase. Por ejemplo, para crear una instancia que trabaje con cadenas podríamos hacer algo tal que:

```
THashCerrada<string> tablaDeCadenas;
```

Ahora pasamos a revisar la función `insertar()`:

```
bool THashCerrada<T>::insertar(long clave, const T& dato)
```

Como vemos, el tipo de `dato` va a ser `T`, que es el tipo del template. ¿Qué tipo es ese? pues depende de la especialización del template. En el caso que hemos indicado más arriba, `dato` sería de tipo `string`:

```
bool THashCerrada<string>::insertar(long clave, const string& dato)
```

Y un ejemplo de la llamada:

```
THashCerrada<string> tablaDeCadenas;
tablaDeCadenas.insertar(123,"abcd");
```

Si, en cambio, hemos creado una tabla has tal que:

```
THashCerrada<int> tablaDeEnteros;
```

Ahora la función `insertar` sería equivalente a:

```
bool THashCerrada<int>::insertar(long clave, const int& dato)
```

Ejemplo:

```
THashCerrada<int> tablaDeEnteros;
tablaDeEnteros.insertar(123,123);
```